# Weierstrass Trig Substitution Proof

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

After browsing some topics here, through one post, I discovered the "miraculous" Weierstrass substitutions. However, I can not find a decent or "simple" proof to follow.

The simplest proof I found is on chapter 3, "Why Does The Miracle Substitution Work?" of this paper: http://www.westga.edu/~faucette/research/Miracle.pdf

---

My question is, from that chapter, can someone please explain to me how algebraically the $\frac{\theta}{2}$ angle is derived?

Or, if you could kindly suggest other sources.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean on this part?

Check it:
$$
\begin{aligned}
t   = \tan \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \implies 
& \frac{\theta}{2} = \arctan\left(t\right) \implies 
\theta = 2 \arctan\left(t\right) \implies 
\\
\implies & d\theta = (2)'\!\cdot\arctan\left(t\right) + 2\!\cdot\!\big(\arctan\left(t\right)\big)'
   = 0 + 2\,\frac{dt}{1 + t^{2}} 
\implies 
\\
\implies &\bbox[4pt, border:1.25pt solid #000000]{d\theta = \frac{2\,dt}{1 + t^{2}}}
\end{aligned}
$$